# Keep elements the same within a div when size changes

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have the following code which supposed to create a sort of notebook opening,

```
<html>
<style>
    #container
    {
        position:absolute;
        width:570px;
        height:360px;
    }
    inner
    {
        height:360px;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        width:570px;
    }
    #div1
    {
        background-color:red;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:360px;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        width:570px;
    }
    #div2
    {
        background-color:yellow;
        overflow:hidden;
        height:360px;
        position: relative;
        float:left;
        width:0px;
    }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var flipped = false;
function flip() {
if (flipped==false)
    {
            $("#div2").animate({
               width: '570px'
            }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
            $("#div1").animate({
               width: '0px'
            }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
        flipped=true;
    }
else
    {
        $("#div2").animate({
            width: '0px'
        }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
        $("#div1").animate({
           width: '570px'
        }, { duration: 2000, queue: false });
        flipped=false;
    }
}
</script>
<body>
    <input type="button" onClick="flip()" value="flip">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="div1">
            <label>Some field:</label><input type="text">
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <label>Some other field:</label><input type="text">
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

I would like for the text and input elements to not change position when the div shrinks / expands. Is this possible?

thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;`

[See JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/QNTs2/)